# Find the file in the folder with specific end in ruby

Tags: ruby, ruby-1.9.3, ruby-1.9

I have many files in the folder, such as mp4, mov, avi files. But I have to find files that are end with "**_college.mp4**".

I tried following way

```
File.exists?("#{temp_dir}/*_college.mp4")
```

But I not worked. How can I do this in ruby.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [`Dir::glob`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Dir.html#method-c-glob) method :

```
Dir.glob("#{temp_dir}/*_college.mp4")
```

Answer (score 3):

[@ArupRakshit answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23434586/1376448) perfectly. I would like to add:

You can even use the shorthand [`Dir[]`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Dir.html#method-c-5B-5D) for `#glob` shorthand:

```
Dir["#{temp_dir}/*_college.mp4"]
```